# Referencing a white paper

Tags: biblatex

I want to reference a white paper with over 50 authors as just author et al. both in the citation and in the bibliography. So how do I let latex know that I want 'author et al.' to be viewed as one word?

Comment: What do you mean by "white paper"?

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? @Alenanno I think 'white paper' is something of a red herring; just assume it's an `@article`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you seem not to want the whole list of authors to appear anywhere, maybe you could manually alter your bib file, with double bracketting to force biblatex to see this phrase as unalterable:

```
@misc{manyauthors,
author = {{Author et al.}}
}
```

Comment: While it could word, I wouldn't do this. It defeats the purpose of BibTeX.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. And as I said this is an exception due to the excessive amount of authors.

Comment: I suppose setting limits to the number of displayed authors both in the citation and in the bibliography would be best practice in this case, but it's tough to propose such a solution without a MWE of what packages and parameters @Anne is using to manage the bibliography (in particular, styles, etc.) My bad then.

Comment: @Anne A better solution is to use the keyword `and others`, i.e. `author = {Uthor, Anne and others}`. Though you have all the 50 authors in your `.bib` file and have your bibliography style truncate the list for you.

Comment: If you use biber, you can use the special "others" Author as in `author = {Author and others}` which automates the "et al" addition and takes care of various name counting issues.