# How to put "et al." for citation with many authors more than two? (roffin.cls, jf.bst)

Tags: bibtex, author-number

I want to put "et al." for citations with many authors more than two instead of full lists of authors. I know there are several similar questions to mine. But, all suggested solution have not worked in my case. I'm using roffin.cls, which is provided by Review of Finance, and jf.bst, which is also provided by Review of Finance. (http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/rof/for_authors/)

I constructed a simple sample code and attached it with .cls and .bst files. Please, let me know how to handle this problem. Thank you.

You can find the files in my Google drive folder: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4YZL9TZ6D20c3JLZzNLUHdQNkU&usp=sharing

Comment: I have the feeling that this is related to (1) the fact that the bst files explicitely requires (in the comments) the harvard package, whereas (2) the cls only requires natbib. I don't think there is a solution without altering the files that are provided by them. Another possibility is to use the `and others` keyword in the author field of the bib file as suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287261/referencing-a-white-paper/287262#comment694731_287262), but you will have the "et al." both in the citation and the full reference (hence not the full list of authors anywhere).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Following your advice, I want to replace jf.bst file to model2-names.bst file. (You can get the file [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4YZL9TZ6D20c3JLZzNLUHdQNkU&usp=sharing).) When I replaced it, The reference at the end of the article is enumerated. If I want to remove the number for each item in the reference, what should I do?

Comment: see here my friend https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379901/biblatex-how-to-match-the-journal-of-finance-bibliographic-style